# Powerbuilder (ver 7) Runtime problems

Tags: runtime, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

We have an old Powerbuilder app running on Server 2000 and need to move it. I am having a problem with moving the Powerbuilder app ver 7.0,  to a newer platform - Server 2003.

We basically moved the directory with the app in it and all the Dlls. Then I registered the ones that would allow it. We also had to set up Informix client-side software and verified that it was able to connect to the Database.

The app basically takes 2 parameters then checks for data in a remote database, then generates a return code to be used by another app. The return code we get is unexpected and I have no luck in looking up the number:

**-1073741811**

The app is run from the command line. When I run the app I get a Windows error that mentions Sybase and msvcr80.dll and a dump, and the return code mentioned above - Here is the error from the manifest text:

```
Server=watson.microsoft.com
UI LCID=1033
Flags=99088
Brand=WINDOWS
TitleName=Sybase Inc. Product File
DigPidRegPath=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId
RegSubPath=Microsoft\PCHealth\ErrorReporting\DW
ErrorText=This error occurred on 2/14/2013 at 7:56:14 AM.
HeaderText=Sybase Inc. Product File encountered a problem and needed to close.
Stage1URL=/StageOne/cert_lsi_exe/7_0_3_10180/msvcr80_dll/8_0_50727_6195/0001e6d5.htm
Stage2URL=/dw/stagetwo.asp?szAppName=cert_lsi.exe&szAppVer=7.0.3.10180&szModName=msvcr80.dll&szModVer=8.0.50727.6195&offset=0001e6d5
ErrorSig=AppName: cert_lsi.exe                AppVer: 7.0.3.10180     ModName: msvcr80.dll                       ModVer: 8.0.50727.6195        Offset: 0001e6d5
DataFiles=C:\DOCUME~1\smarkley\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\WER1.tmp.dir00\cert_lsi.exe.mdmp|C:\DOCUME~1\smarkley\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\WER1.tmp.dir00\appcompat.txt
Heap=C:\DOCUME~1\smarkley\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\WER1.tmp.dir00\cert_lsi.exe.hdmp
ErrorSubPath=cert_lsi.exe\7.0.3.10180\msvcr80.dll\8.0.50727.6195\0001e6d5
```

I am surprised by the msvcr80.dll request, because this app was written around 2003 and I didnt think that c compiler was at ver 8 yet. I have used Dependency Walker and see no complaints there. I am probably in DLLHell with this thing, though... does anyone have any ideas what to look for?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I still have a few PB 7 applications around.

Did you try Application Compatibility?

Navigate to the folder and right click on the executable and choose the Compatibility tab.

I suggest trying

> Run this program in compatibility for `Windows XP (Service Pack 3)`
>
> Privilege Level `[x] Run this program as administrator`

You may need to use `Windows XP (Service Pack 2)` or an earlier version of Windows.